# Javascript For Loop HTML syntax with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm pretty new to Javascript so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.  First off I'm using JSON to create an array object 'providerlisting'.  Next I am creating a for loop and it should loop through the html until there are no more listings in the JSON array. I'm not sure that I did the syntax correctly.  I'm also kind of new to asking these questions so I'm sorry in advance if I'm doing this incorrectly.

```
for (var i=0;i<providerlisting.length;i++)
{ document.write('<div class="entry panel row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns first">
                        <div class="name">'providerlisting.nametitle[i]'</div>
                        <div class="specialty">'providerlisting.caretype[i]'</div>
                        <div class="peferred">'providerlisting.preferredprovider[i]'</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-3 columns second">
                        <div class="address">'providerlisting.address1[i]'<br />
                        'providerlisting.address2[i]'<br />
                        'providerlisting.citystatezip[i]'
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-3 columns third">
                        <img src="'providerlisting.coverage[i]'" alt="example">
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-2 columns fourth">
                        <div class="status">'providerlisting.status[i]'</div>
                        <a data-dropdown="actionsMenu2" class="actions button small secondary round dropdown" href="#">Actions</a><br>
                        <ul id="actionsMenu2" data-dropdown-content="" class="f-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="'providerlisting.psn[i]'">Generate PSN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="'providerlisting.dcontact[i]'">Download Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="'providerlisting.save[i]'">Save to Provider List</a></li>
                            <li><a href="'providerlisting.rating[i]'">View Healthgrades Rating</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
     ');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: (Escaping assumed of course). I would suggest concatenating those string or formatting them into one.

Comment: In addition to escaped newlines, you also need `+` operators to concatenate your variables and string literals.

Comment: thanks guys, other than that it should be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly because you haven't posted your JSON, but this should do it:

```
for(var i = 0; i < providerlisting.length; i++) {
    document.write('<div class="entry panel row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns first">
                        <div class="name">'+ providerlisting[i].nametitle +'</div>
                        <div class="specialty">'+ providerlisting[i].caretype +'</div>
                        <div class="peferred">'+ providerlisting[i].preferredprovider +'</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-3 columns second">
                        <div class="address">'+ providerlisting[i].address1 +'<br />
                        '+ providerlisting[i].address2 +'<br />
                        '+ providerlisting[i].citystatezip +'
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-3 columns third">
                        <img src="'+ providerlisting[i].coverage +'" alt="example">
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-2 columns fourth">
                        <div class="status">'+ providerlisting[i].status +'</div>
                        <a data-dropdown="actionsMenu2" class="actions button small secondary round dropdown" href="#">Actions</a><br>
                        <ul id="actionsMenu2" data-dropdown-content="" class="f-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="'+ providerlisting[i].psn +'">Generate PSN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="'+ providerlisting[i].dcontact +'">Download Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="'+ providerlisting[i].save +'">Save to Provider List</a></li>
                            <li><a href="'+ providerlisting[i].rating +'">View Healthgrades Rating</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>');
}
```

I changed every `providerlisting.prop[i]` into `providerlisting[i].prop`.
You were also stringing together in the wrong way:

`var str = 'some words'someVariable'more words'` won't work.

`var str = 'some words'+ someVariable +'more words'` will.

Comment: Ah you're Right! I didn't catch the [i] thing.  Thanks!